# Cumulative Custom Build Steps in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, custom-build-step

Is it possible to have cumulative custom build steps in Visual Studio?

What I want to do is have a

```
if not exist "$(OutDir)" mkdir "$(OutDir)"
```

as a custom step for ALL configurations (current and possible future ones)

But for a specific **configuration** (say *Deploy*) I want to ADDITIONALLY do this

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)..\Resources" "$(OutDir)" /D /E /I /F /Y
```

Is this possible? I have tried adding a property sheet in *Deploy* with the **xcopy** command, but the ***All Configurations*** *"custom build step"* property (with the **mkdir** command) seems to completely overshadow the **xcopy** one!

Comment: Isn't OutDir created automatically by the build already?

Comment: @stijn Yeah, but I am using it as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to have a `%(Command)` added at the end of EVERY **commands list** to make the commands ***inheritable***.

Answer found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22749337/113718

Having to add an extra "command" feels very *hackish*, if there is another, better solution, please share.

Comment: There's not much hackish about this, it is just how one works with variables in msbuild: when declaring them again they get overwritten. Like in other languages if you say 'a = 1', then 'a=2', the latter declartion overrides the former. Why would you expect it to be '12' or '3' or whatever? So if you want to append, there's no other way than to reference the original value and add the new one to it.

Comment: @stijn You are right about how variables work, but one would expect *Commands* and command lines to not be interpreted as mere variables but rather as cumulative *lists*. Automagically.

Comment: Ok but if that were the case then you woudn't be able to actually override them anymore. Unless they added another 'magic' way for that. So that's likely why the devs wanted to keep it simple and have one way which can achieve anything.

Comment: @Bill Kotsias, Since you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution: you can easily have this functionality by using for instance

```
<Target Name="MyTarget" BeforeTargets="BscMake">
  <Exec Command="xcopy ..."/>
</Target>`
```

That will run right before BscMake, which is when a custom build step with default options also runs. Or you could also use `AfterTargets="CustomBuildStep"` to make it run after your CustomBuildStep, etc. Note this method also makes it easy to add more steps without interfering with others.